# Queue of AsyncTasks on Listview, how to get rid of no longer needed ones?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am using AsyncTasks to load data to items in a listview to avoid a laggy scroll, I am getting everything from webservices including bitmaps but I have that part covered.

From what I gather, items with running threads won't be recycled, only when the thread stops, the thread at least keeps running, I placed a few system.out.println to keep track of what's happening and I noticed that if I scroll down the listview quickly, say 20 events, even though I am only seeing 3 or 4 I see the outputs on the logcat of all the `System.out.println`, one every 1/4 second or so which is roughly the time it takes to load each image and other text stuff.

So I need to wait an unacceptable amount of time til it gets to the currently visible items since there can be only one AsyncTask running at any given moment, I know there are ways to run multiple threads but I want to avoid that path since I am afraid it may overload the phone and in this case I am pretty sure it would result in a out.of.memory error.

If I scroll too fast I will scroll items that have not even been loaded yet, still their threads jump to the queue, I am running AsyncTask inside custom adapters, every time a item gets created the thread starts or their threads get queued and when scrolling fast some items that are no longer visible still have their threads queued and they end up delaying the ones visible for nothing just to be destroyed immediately after the thread is finished.

I already tried using a setRecyclerListener inside the custom adapter but only the initial visible items got loaded and when scrolling down nothing would show up.

If you have any suggestion don't bother going through the code but I'll leave it here anyway but what I was really looking for was ideas to avoid this, they may require minor adjustments to my code or rebuilding the whole class as long as they work.

On the code I am posting is with the recyclerListener, one thing that I may be missing is that to use the listener I had to associate it to a listview and I am inside the custom adapter class so on the listview main class I declared the listview as a public variable and got it into the custom adapter class that way.

/////////////////////////////////

```
class CustomAdapterEvents extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
private AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> listviewTextAssembler;
private AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> listviewImageAssembler;
public CustomAdapterEvents(Context context, ArrayList<String> IDlist) {
    super(context, R.layout.custom_row_events, IDlist);

}
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    LayoutInflater inflater2 = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    final View customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row_events, parent, false);
    final View customView2 = inflater2.inflate(R.layout.custom_row_trending, parent, false);

    //Trending Items
    final TextView trendingTitle = (TextView)   customView2.findViewById(R.id.trendingEventTitle);
    final TextView trendingDate = (TextView) customView2.findViewById(R.id.trendingEventDate);
    final TextView trendingHour = (TextView) customView2.findViewById(R.id.trendingEventHour);
    final TextView trendingSpot = (TextView) customView2.findViewById(R.id.trendingEventSpot);
    ImageView trendingImage = (ImageView) customView2.findViewById(R.id.trendingEventImage);
    //Trending Items
    final TextView listviewTitle = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.listEventTitle);
    final TextView listviewDate = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.listEventDate);
    final TextView listviewHour = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.listEventHour);
    final TextView listviewSpot = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.listEventSpot);
    final ImageView listviewImage = (ImageView) customView.findViewById(R.id.listEventImage);
    ///////////////
    final RotateAnimation anim = new RotateAnimation(0f, 359f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    final ImageView loading = (ImageView) customView.findViewById(R.id.loadingView);
    anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    anim.setDuration(700);
    loading.startAnimation(anim);

    TypeFaceUtil.overrideFont(getContext(), "SERIF", "fonts/lato-reg.ttf");


    MainScreen.listview.setRecyclerListener(new AbsListView.RecyclerListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMovedToScrapHeap(View view) {
            System.out.println("cancel that *%$# for *%#!'s sake!");
            listviewImageAssembler.cancel(true);
            listviewTextAssembler.cancel(true);
        }
    });

        ///LISTVIEW PROCESS
        listviewTextAssembler = new AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject>(){
            protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
                int position = Integer.parseInt(params[0]);
                //GET JSON
                String result = "";
                WebConnector connector = new WebConnector();
                try {result = connector.getResponseText("listview/1");}
                catch (MalformedURLException e) {}
                catch (IOException e){}
                /////////

                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
                JSONObject completeJson = new JSONObject();
                String thumbnail = "";
                JSONObject eventJson = new JSONObject();

                try {
                    completeJson = new JSONObject(result);
                    jsonArray = completeJson.getJSONArray("eventos");
                    eventJson = jsonArray.getJSONObject(position-1);
                    thumbnail = eventJson.getString("thumbnail");
                }catch (JSONException e){e.printStackTrace();}
                System.out.println("EVENT > "+eventJson);
                return eventJson;
            }
            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onPostExecute(JSONObject eventJson)
            {
                loading.setAnimation(null);
                loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                String id = "";
                String title = "";
                String date = "";
                String hour = "";
                String address = "";
                Bitmap image = null;
                try{
                    title = eventJson.getString("title");
                    date = eventJson.getString("date");
                    hour = eventJson.getString("time");
                    address = eventJson.getString("city");
                }catch (JSONException e){e.printStackTrace();}
                listviewTitle.setText(title);
                listviewDate.setText(date);
                listviewHour.setText(hour);
                listviewSpot.setText(address);
            }
        };
        listviewImageAssembler = new AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>(){
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
                int position = Integer.parseInt(params[0]);

                //GET JSON
                String result = "";
                WebConnector connector = new WebConnector();
                try {result = connector.getResponseText("listview/1");}
                catch (MalformedURLException e) {}
                catch (IOException e){}
                /////////

                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
                JSONObject completeJson = new JSONObject();
                String thumbnail = "";
                JSONObject eventJson = new JSONObject();

                try {
                    completeJson = new JSONObject(result);
                    jsonArray = completeJson.getJSONArray("eventos");
                    eventJson = jsonArray.getJSONObject(position);
                    thumbnail = eventJson.getString("thumbnail");
                }catch (JSONException e){e.printStackTrace();}
                System.out.println("EVENT > "+eventJson);

                Bitmap image = connector.drawable_from_url(thumbnail);

                return image;
            }
            @Override
            public void onPostExecute(Bitmap image)
            {
                listviewImage.setImageBitmap(image);
                image = null;
            }
        };
        String pos = ""+position;
        listviewTextAssembler.execute(pos);
        listviewImageAssembler.execute(pos);
        return customView;

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using:
listviewTextAssembler.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, pos);
instead of:
listviewTextAssembler.execute(pos);

pos is just a string i pass along...

This is what i was trying to avoid but it will have to do for now... Will be looking forward for suggestions though on how to kill running threads that are no longer useful or remove others from the queue or use a Last in First out model and limit the number of threads to 5 which is the maximum items that are visible at once. Not short of ideas, just short on know-how but i guess it's all part of the learning curve.

Cheers